# nodejs application executed that time I got this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I downloaded node.js code from github then executed that code I got this error.

```
module.js:540
throw err;
^


  Error: Cannot find module 'D:\compiler-using-hackerrank-api-master\index.jade'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` before you run the app?

Comment: Seems like you forgot to install the module `throw`. Open your cmd and head to `D:\compiler-using-hackerrank-api-master`, then run `npm install throw`. Then simply run it again. I guess that should do the trick.

Comment: @sam yes i had done before run the app

Comment: @CodeF0x  yea i done npm install throw also getting same error

Comment: Did you run it in the exact same directory your Node.js app is?